# Не могу подключить php к Js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

На страничке html есть кнопка, при нажатии которой данные должны отправляться на php  скрипт

Я это реализовал с помощью jQuery и ajax.
Для простоты я написал php, который просто выводит сообщение.
 Проблема заключается в том, что jQuery выдает ошибку, что php файл не найден.

Я ставил сайт на локальный хост с помощью Open Server, пробовал через специальное расширение в гугле, но ничего не помогает.

**Ошибка-**

```
Failed to load resource: 
the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).
```

Если нажать на ошибку, то выводит- entry not found: /phpСЃheckHitPoint.php

```
 $("#formSubmit_check").click(function (e) {
    var x = $('input[name="coordinateX"]:checked').val();
    var y = $("#coordinateY").val();
    var y = parseInt(y);
    var r = $("#coordinateR").val();
    if (isNaN(y) || y > 3 || y < -3 || y == undefined || x == undefined) {
        if (isNaN(y) || y > 3 || y < -3 || y == undefined) {
            $('#rezult').text('Неверные данные');
        }
        if (x === undefined) {
            $('#rezultX').text('Неверные данные');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#rezultX').text('');
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#rezult').text('');
        $('#rezultX').text('');
        $.ajax({
            url: "php\сheckHitPoint.php",
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: $('#checkForm').serialize(),
            dataType: 'html',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#formSubmit_check").prop("disabled", true);
            },
            success: function (data) {

                if (!data) {
                    alert("Произошла ошибка получения данных");
                }
                else {
                    $("#checkForm").trigger("resert");
                }
                $("#formSubmit_check").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    }
}
);
```

Сам php файл

```
<?php
 echo 'Hello';?>
```

Comment: Видно же что в имени файла какой-то левый символ. **Просто стереть и написать заново.**

Comment: Вместо "php\сheckHitPoint.php" я бы написал "php/сheckHitPoint.php" для начала. И комментатор выше - прав.